# Equivalence of inequality and set membership

Tags: logic

Notationally, can one freely swap between statements of inequality and statements of membership? For example, are the statements $x>2$ and $x \in (2, \infty)$ equivalent?

Comment: Yes it is, by definition of $(2,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in general, statements involving **the standard order $\leq$ on the real numbers** have equivalent reformulations in terms of membership in subsets of $\bf R$.

The same can be said for any partial order $\preceq$ (or indeed for any relation $R$ at all) defined on any set $X$, assuming the appropriate terminology or notation for specifying the corresponding subsets exists or gets defined.

That this is so can be seen from the fact that the **definition** of a (binary) relation on $X$ is “a subset of $X \times X$.” So a statement of the form $x R y$ for some $x,y\in X$ can be understood to mean that $x$ is in the subset $X_R(y)$ of $X$ consisting of all those elements of $X$ that are related to $y$ by $R$, which is to say,
$$xRy \mbox{ means exactly }
x\in X_R(y) = \{z\in X : (z,y) \in R\}.
$$

If your statement involving $R$ is a complicated one built up with *and*’s and *or*’s, then the corresponding set-membership statement will be a compound one expressible in terms of intersections and unions.